# FCFS disk scheduling

Tags: disk, scheduling

I want to find head movement through Disk Scheduling **first come first serve** algorithm 
**queue =** 98, 183, 37, 122, 14, 124, 65, 67
**head start at** 53

I have confused because this same quotation two book different answer first give  head movement of **236 cylinders** and other book answer **640 cylinders**. I don't know which one correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. I think without giving _much_ more context, the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From   53  to   98  =   98−53 =   **45**
From   98  to 183  = 183−98 =   **85**
From 183  to   37  = 183−37 = **146**
From   37  to 122  = 122−37 =   **85**
From 122  to   14  = 122−14 = **108**
From   14  to 124  = 124−14 = **110**
From 124  to   65  = 124−65 =   **59**
From   65  to   67  =   67−65 =     **2**

45 + 85 + 146 + 85 + 108 + 110 + 59 + 2 = **640**

You would get different results if you stipulated that
the 98, 183, 37, 122, 14, 124, 65, and 67 were *track* numbers,
with multiple tracks per cylinder,
but (after a few minutes of trying various assumptions),
I couldn’t get it to come out to 236.